# Socket iO not working in my angular project

Tags: javascript, angular

> I have an endpoint with post method which is working fine, once i integrated that in socket io it return some error regarding connection error and method not found.  would any help me on this if someone is provide some source code that will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could provide some code example, and which back end do you use ?

Comment: i have backend in on rasa endpoint having post method access. 
would you please share some snippet or suggest how to achieve... my goal is to create real time chat window where a user intract with database sometimes also if without user input database will respond

Answer (score 0):

See the example, i use socket.io-client

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eb3li7